# Low level Keyboard Hook in C#

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard, hook

I'm making a module that will control and move pan and tilt device via KEYBOARD.
The module is a C# .DLL and being loaded dynamiclally via other module using reflection.
The module CAN NOT have any form (visible).

I'm using a code that I found on the http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx for a low level kb hook.
The only problem that is it uses consol application and calls Application.Run() to take care of a message loop, which is required for hooks to work properly. Since I'm having a .dll and not a console application, I can not make it to work and catch the keys pressed.

The question:
How can I replace the call for Application.Run() to take care of a message loop in the .dll to catch the KB hooks?

Thx!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your DLL should use the message loop from the program loading it. However if that is not possible you can have your DLL start a new thread and call Application.Run() from inside that thread and use it's own message loop.

```
public static void InjectionPoint()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DLLMessageLoop));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}

public static void DLLMessageLoop()
{
    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    Application.Run();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a message-loop there is no need to have Console or GUI - it can remain hidden, and intercept messages.